# How to make Horizental scrolling using RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi i am very beginner for android and in my app i am using RecyclerView for showing ListView records ok it's working fine when scroll records at Vertically as like my below screen1

But when i change the Listview for Horizontally then records are not display at perfect manner as like my screen2

please help me some how can i resolve this problem

### Recycler_layout.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### list_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:text="countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:text="populationlabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### RecyclerActivity:

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        myList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

### screen1:

[image]

### screen2:

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? do you want to make screen 1 and got screen 2?

Comment: Actually screen1 fitting perfectly but in screen2 i want make Horizentall scrolling using recyclerview but fields are not fitting that's what my problem

Comment: but looking at the data of a particular row, i would suggest that you use viewpager

Comment: but why i am getting this problem actually recyclerview main purpose we scroll the both horizentally and vertically

Comment: why don't we use this ?

Comment: and if you still want to use recycler view, i think you should mark your layout's width as wrap_content and place the child tags properly(give a fixed margin to the icon, relative to the text), it will surely work out.

Comment: @SarthakMittal i am very new for android just two days back i came into this technology please modified my code and post

Comment: we can use this, i just am not clear about your use case

Comment: @sarthakMittal u there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ranklabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ranklabel"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:text="countrylabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/countrylabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countrylabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/countrylabel"

        android:text="populationlabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/populationlabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/populationlabel"/>


</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have wrapped the RelativeLayout around a LinearLayout to align the ImageView to left of the TextView's. Now, no matter which TextView takes what size, your layout won't break.

Comment: let me try and i will tell u

Comment: hello @Sarthak Mittal i want to put imageview at layout_alightRightToParent even in Vertically and horizentally when we change

Comment: u see my screen1 i want to maintain same at both horizentally mode and vertically mode

Comment: can't we give right margin for imageview from parentView i mean if we give right margin for imageview then for all screen it's fitting perfectly

Comment: can't understand what u r saying, hope my answer helped :)

Comment: android:layout_marginRight="10dp" i mean if we set like this then image  look at right side even if we run app in tab,Right?

Comment: no, i don't think so, i gave layout_weight to the relative layout that is why the image is showing up at the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106078/discussion-between-abhiram-and-sarthak-mittal).

Answer (score 0):

If you use LinearLayout to create  your list layout  that will solve your problem or you can also use  this code in ImageView `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/country"`

Comment: how can i resolve this problem if i only set suppose to be android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/country" tha't not working in my case

Comment: so You may use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout